# install/update ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am getting this error when I try to install/update my ClickOnce application:
The file, Focus Studio Acc.exe.config, has a different calculated hash than the hash specified in the manifest.
I already tried adding a new config, remade the whole project, but nothing has fixed the error.

Some more info:
- I signed the application with a test certificate (.pfx)
- I did not sign the assemblies
- I did enable the security settings (full trust)
- I did select the option that adds .deploy to the files
- I am working with Visual Studio 2015

Does anyone here knows what other solutions I can try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are trying to install this on an XP machine.  This comes down to using SHA256 over SHA1 in .NET 4.0.  At least, that is where I have seen it.  XP does not support a SHA256 in .NET 4.0 so this is why it fails.

Comment: It's not XP, I sent the publish to a windows server 2008 and then install the application on different windows 7 machines. The application did work for more than a year, it's the latest update where I first got the problem. I tried to remove it and reinstall but  that didn't work either.

Comment: OK, do you have the full deployment log?  That will say what assembly is being mismatched and give us a starting point to carry on.  If possible, try re-adding the reference if it is a referenced assembly.

Comment: It's the first time I use this site, how can I add the file? And I have found only one log file.  if this is not the file you're asking for can you help me to find the file you need but first I need to be able to show the file....

Comment: You could put your file on pastebin, and link it here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you can find the file here : https://pastebin.com/mnV9mLBm. And as I said before, I hope it's the right one. If not guid me through please.

Comment: If you are targetting .NET Framework 4.0, try updating this to 4.5 or later. (Project -> Properties -> Application -> Target Framework).

Comment: I took a fresh look at the log file today, and noticed that you have it using Q: as the drive to install from.  Can you try copying the installation folder locally to the PC and running the install from there?  I want to eliminate any potential security issues revolving around you doing this on a mapped drive.

Comment: I copied the installation folder local and tried to install from here but still the same problem. I got exactly the same error file as before.